# 4-Section Interactive Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm working on an interactive graphic. There are 4 parts. When one is clicked, I'm checking to see if the others are open and if they're, I'm resetting them.

The section I'm talking about is located here: http://lemieux-design.net/profitero/ It's the circle graphic.

The client also wants the user to be able to collapse any open part. I'm not sure if I can do that with all of the other conditionals going on. Any guesses?

Comment: You should add your own guess, what you've tried and if you ran into any problem with that? - but to give you my guess, if the others aren't open, it means it's just that one that is, so you could just collapse it on that condition?

Comment: I tried the jQuery toggle method, but when I did that, it broke the rest of my code. Ah, I like your logic. I'll try to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible.

Firstly instead of having all the different types of checks you can simply your solution in two ways:

1. Remove the TweenLite dependency, everything you use it for (as far as I can tell) you can do easily with CSS animations.
2. Since you're using jQuery for your selectors you can use a general selector and target siblings the way that I've done in the example below.

Here's the JS solution (check jsbin-link for accompanying CSS and minor changes to HTML):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.availability').addClass('active');
    var interactiveEls = $('.interactive h5');
    var activeSections;

    $(interactiveEls).each(function(index) {
        $(this).on("click", { idx: index }, function(e) {
            activeSections = $('.col-md-12.circle-activity > div.active');
            if (!(activeSections.length === 1 && $(e.target).parent().hasClass('active'))) {
            $(e.target)
                .parent()
                .toggleClass("active");

                var isActive = $(e.target).parent().hasClass('active') ? true : false;
                var mainImg = $(e.target).parent().siblings('.main-img').find('img');

                toggleMainImg(isActive, mainImg, index);
            }
        });
    });

    function toggleMainImg(isActive, mainImg, index) {
        // a slightly icky switch-case for checking the index against so we know which circ-image needs to be set as the img src.
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                isActive ? mainImg.prop('src', 'http://lemieux-design.net/profitero/img/circ-4.png') : '';
                break;
            case 1:
                isActive ? mainImg.prop('src', 'http://lemieux-design.net/profitero/img/circ-1.png') : '';
                break;
            case 2:
                isActive ? mainImg.prop('src', 'http://lemieux-design.net/profitero/img/circ-3.png') : '';
                break;
            case 3:
                isActive ? mainImg.prop('src', 'http://lemieux-design.net/profitero/img/circ-2.png') : '';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/derazegulo/1/edit?html,js,output

An added bonus would be to get rid of the images you're using and do:

1. The plus and minus buttons could be either a font-icon or turned into SVGs for better performance.
2. Also for the main-img you could either a) match the index to the names of the images, which would make the switch-case unnecessary, or b) turn that into entire thing into CSS (or again SVG).

Comment: A Switch statement is brilliant! Thanks so much. I looked at your example though and it didn't seem to do what I expected it to do. I'll have to look into it deeper though. On the GSAP thing, I've heard that the performance is much better than CSS animations and has better tweening capabilities.

Comment: If the example doesn't work try pressing the "run with js"-button on JSBin. I think if you change the naming of your images to match the indices you'll be able to reste the `circ-img` as well.

As for the GSAP vs CSS stuff you really aren't using that complex animation stuff in this particular instance, that's why I chose to replace it :).

What is it that isn't working as expected?